# R displaying unicode/utf-8 encoding rather the special characters

Tags: r, encoding, view

I have a dataframe in R which has one row of utf-8 encoded special characters and one integer row.

If I display both rows, or go into the view(), I do not see the characters displayed correctly. 
However, if I only select the row with the special characters, it works. Any ideas?

This is the output (if I paste it, the encoding disappears): 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in R. I've worked around a number of these in the **corpus** package. Try the following

```
library(corpus)
print.corpus_frame(WW_mapping[1:3,])
```

Alternatively, do

```
library(corpus)
class(WW_mapping) <- c("corpus_frame", "data.frame")
WW_mapping[1:3,]
```

Adding the `"corpus_frame"` class to the data frame changes the `print` and `format` methods; otherwise, it does not change the behavior of the object.

If that doesn't work, please report your `sessionInfo()` along with `dput(WW_mapping)`. (Actually, even if this fix *does* work, please report this information so that we can let the R core developers know about the problem.)